# Como tornar o main formulario invisivel c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Como fazer o formulario principal, criado pelo Visual Studio ficar invisivel após abrir outro? Tentei usar o comando "hide();", mas não tive sucesso.

codigo :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
        // no caso ao abrir o Form2, o Form1 ficar invisivel.
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem que ser com o Hide mesmo, acabei de testar aqui, e funciona:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2();
        f.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Aqui também, esqueci que tinha de usar o "this"

Answer (score 1):

Bom também é possível assim, mas por curiosidade já que é utilizado para deixar o form transparente:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            this.Opacity = 0;
            f.ShowDialog();
            this.Opacity = 1;

        }
```

Comment: acredito que a propriedade Opacity varie entre 0.0 e 1.0 mas se é pra esconder o form, tem que ser no Hide mesmo, dessa forma, ele fica invisível mais ainda acessível.

Comment: Mas não é a resposta e mais uma curiosidade. Mesmo com showDialog() ele fica acessivel.

Comment: entendo que é apenas curiosidade, mas apenas para deixar registrado para futuros leitores, e sem entrar na questão do ShowDialog (que aí o de baixo não vai estar acessível), apenas comentando sobre a Opacity mesmo.

Comment: Você está certo. Obrigado